# Cannot open database 'dbname' requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp-classic

*Firstly, I know that there are a lot of similar topics, but none seem to solve my problem.*

I have inherited a project where the front-end is built in ASP.NET and the CMS is built in classic ASP. I'm in the process of setting up a local development environment where I've copied the database from the live server and am configuring the website to connect to my new local DB.

The ASP.NET part is connecting with the connection string `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=DBNAME; Trusted_Connection=True;` but I had to mess about with Application Pools and Permissions.

I'm having a problem with getting the classic ASP part of the website to connect to the SQL database. The error I am recieving is:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "DBNAME" requested by the login. The login failed.

/cms/connections/Conn.asp, line 18
```

The code in that file is:

```
12. Dim Conn_STRING, URL, mailHost
13. Conn_STRING = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=DBNAME; Trusted_Connection=True;"

15. Dim conn
16. set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
17. conn.ConnectionString = Conn_STRING
18. conn.Open
```

I know it's a permission problem or some sort, but I can't get to the bottom of it. I'll appreciate any help at all :)

Comment: How are the two sites intermingled?  In other words, do they share an APP pool?  Also, what version of IIS are you running?

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm a PHP developer so APP pool and the like are foreign to me I'm afraid. The website simply has a cms folder which has the asp files and folders inside it. Also, I'm running IIS 6.1.

Comment: There is no such thing as IIS 6.1..  There is 6.0 (windows 2003 and XP), 7.0 (windows 2008 and Vista) and 7.5 (windows 2008 R2 and Win 7)...

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium and it looks like [IIS 6.1. Oh wait, It's 7.5](http://i.imgur.com/N9OHP.jpg)

Comment: If the application is running under IIS, make sure to give the NETWORK SERVICE account access to the database.

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm, well, the asp.net part is using SQLExpress, connected via an attached file.  DBNAME in the first example is going to refer to a db file name in the actual asp.net project.  It's been quite a long time since I last used classic ASP, but I'd be STUNNED if it supports this.  You need to attach the db file to an actual sql server and use it that way.

```
server=mycomputername\sqlexpress; database=DBNAME; user id=username; password=password
```

Comment: its not using an attached file name as per his connection string though - that uses a different syntax. he is going directly against the instance via .\\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: This site is currently working live at the moment, thus me needing a local copy to develop. The connection string online is: "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS; Database=DBNAME; Uid=username; Pwd=pass;" I thought I could use the trusted connection like ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open your database in sql express mngmt studio 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593
Go into your security settings for that user and set the default database to "dbname" (whatver your real dbname is of course)

Ensure your app pool is set to run under the user that has permissions to that database. It may just be easier to enable mixed mode authentication and create a sql user to connect to the database rather than messing around with windows authentication on an app pool.
You wil lof course need to change your connection string then to support the sql authentication if you go that route.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143705%28v=sql.90%29.aspx